# Function to hide/unhide non adjacent columns

Tags: google-apps-script, foreach

I would like to create a function to hide/unhide non adjacent columns

I've tried that code (I4ve copied/paste from the forum) but as I don't understand what "hide=>" for example, I'm lost. Is it a variable?

Thanks if you could help me

```
function myFunction() {
  //list of columns that I want to hide/unhide
  const hideColumns = [0,1,3,7,15];

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const requests = [];
  
  // Create request for hiding/unhiding the hide columns.
  if (hideColumns.length > 0) {
    //unhidding hidden columns
    hideColumns.forEach(show=>{
    sheet.showColumn(sheet.getRange(1,show));
    sheet.getRange(11,1).activate();
  }
  }
  else {
    //hiddenning columns
    hideColumns.forEach(hide=>{
    sheet.hideColumn(sheet.getRange(1,hide));
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: You can find information about Array methods here - [Array.methods()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: Take your time learn some of these methods you will find them essential in your programming.

Comment: hide is a variable that is replaced by element of the elements in the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use foreach loop for hideColumns array

```
show=>
```

Means the current element of array in loop.

It means you give a name of that element in array for loop.

Example;

```
    hideColumns.forEach(value=>{
  
      sheet.hideColumn(sheet.getRange(1,value)); // as you can see we used "value" in here to represent the elements in loop.
    })
```

Other example;

We have an array named "numbers" and there are numbers in it. We want to get all numbers and do something for everynumber such as printing or logging to console.

```
numbers.forEach(number => console.log(number))
```

You should look for arrays and loops to understand better.